# displaing the first elements of set

Tags: c++, c++11, printing, c++14

I try to display the first elements of a `std::set`. For each time I would like to display the remaining elements.

For example a set: `4 6 8 9`.

- the first element is `4` the rest of the set is `6 8 9`.
- the first two elements are `4 6` the rest is `8 9`.
- then the first three elements are `4, 6, 8` the rest: `9`.

The code I begun with:

```
for (std::set<int>::iterator it = my_set.begin(); it != my_set.end(); ++it)
{
        std::vector<decltype(*it)> items((my_set.begin()), *it);
        // items is a vector containing successively the n first elements
}
```

With this code I have errors and I can't have the rest of the set after displaying the first elements.
Can you help me?

Comment: Sounds like you need two loops.

Comment: I believe your looking for std::partition

Comment: If you have errors, it's generally helpful to paste them in the question

Answer (score 2):

The vector constructor you are looking for is the one taking iterators:

```
std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(*it)>> items(my_set.begin(), it);
```

But you don't need intermediate `std::vector`, you might directly work with the range (with iterators)
You might use something like:

```
template <typename IT>
void print(IT begin, IT end)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout << sep << *it;
        sep = ",";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s{4, 6, 8, 9};

    for (auto it = std::next(s.begin()); it != s.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << "First elements: "; print(s.begin(), it);
        std::cout << ", Rest: "; print(it, s.end()); std::cout << std::endl;   
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/0yFH5L)

Answer (score 0):

If you want independent functions for `N` first elements and the rest:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void printHead(set<T>& mySet, unsigned int position) {
    for (auto it = mySet.begin(); it != next(mySet.begin(), position); it++) {
        cout << *it << ' ';
    }

    cout << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void printTail(set<T>& mySet, unsigned int position) {
    for (auto it = next(mySet.begin(), position); it != mySet.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << ' ';
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main(void) {
    set<int> foo{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    const auto N = 3;

    cout << "First " << N << " elements: ";
    printHead(foo, N);

    cout << "The rest: ";
    printTail(foo, N);
}
```

Comment: simpler to pass iterator instead of container + position. `std::next` might help.

Comment: I don't want pass iterator, I want pass container and position to function, which calculate iterators for me. But it's great idea to use `next`, so I've edited my code.